# What is the auto-covarriance of a stationary AR1 process?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, autoregressive

Say a stationary AR(1) process is given by:

$$ X_t = c  +  \phi X_{t-1} + \epsilon_t  
$$
where $ \epsilon_t $ is a white noise process with zero mean and constant variance $ \sigma^2 $. 
Wikipedia tells me that the one period auto-covariance is given by
$$ (\sigma^2 \phi) / (1-\phi^2)
$$
but I cannot see why.  Can anyone help me refresh my memory as to why this is true?

Comment: The thread at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123796/conceptual-questions-variance-of-a-process has enough information to answer this question. It computes the variance and shows how to use the same technique to find the autocovariance at any lag.  If that's not perfectly clear, see the follow-up at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123943/conceptual-question-autocorrelation-of-autoregressive-process. The answer includes a formula for the lag-1 autocovariance (which is needed to compute the autocorrelation).

Answer (score 5):

Let $\mu$ denote the mean of the process, then the  first order autocovariance is given by:

$$
E\left[(X_t - \mu)(X_{t-1} - \mu)\right] = E\left[\tilde{X}_t \tilde{X}_{t-1}\right] = \\
E\left[(\phi \tilde{X}_{t-1} + \epsilon_t) \tilde{X}_{t-1}\right] =
\phi \underbrace{E\left[\tilde{X}_{t-1}^2\right]}_{\sigma^2_X} + 
\underbrace{E\left[\epsilon_t \tilde{X}_{t-1}\right]}_{0} = \phi\sigma^2_X \,.
\qquad (1)
$$

The second expectation is zero because $\tilde{X}_{t-1}$ dependes on the innovations $\epsilon_{t-1}$, $\epsilon_{t-2}$,... but not on $\epsilon_t$.

The first expectation is the variance of the AR(1) process, denoted $\sigma^2_X$. The expression for the variance of $X_t$ can be obtained as:

$$
\hbox{Var }(X_t) = \phi^2 \hbox{Var }(X_{t-1}) + 
\underbrace{\hbox{Var }(\epsilon_t)}_{\sigma^2_\epsilon} \,.
$$

As the process is stationary $\hbox{Var }(X_t) = \hbox{Var }(X_{t-1})$. Thus, the above expression can be written as:

$$
\hbox{Var }(X_t) = \frac{\sigma^2_\epsilon}{1 - \phi^2} \,. \qquad (2)
$$

Substituting (2) in (1) gives the following expression for the first order autocovariance:

$$
\frac{\phi \sigma^2_\epsilon}{1 - \phi^2} \,.
$$